# JAVAFX:OnAction event with parameters

Tags: java, oop, button, javafx

I am making a simple chess game with javaFX.
I create my chessboard by using an fxml file, and i used a gridPane with a button inside each cell.
When the user press a button, i want to get the column and rown index of the pressed button.
Is there a way to do this?
I was thinking about using a function like this, but it is not working.

```
private void buttonClicked(MouseEvent event) {                
  Button btn = (Button) event.getSource();
  String nome = btn.getId();
  Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
  alert.setTitle(nome);
  alert.setHeaderText(null);
  alert.setContentText(nome);
  alert.showAndWait();
}
```

I also made the same function trying to print the id of the parent, but is still not working. On the fxml file, the call to this function is the following:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
  <children>
    <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="19.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClicked" prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="94.0" styleClass="blackButton" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: You cannot use a method taking `MouseEvent` as parameter for a `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`. The parameter type needs to be an `Event` of the same type as the `EventHandler` type parameter or a supertype.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass parameter to the buttonclicked Handler.

But you can retrieve row/column coordinate with :

```
AnchorPane cellAnchorPane = (AnchorPane) btn.getParent();
int row = GridPane.getRowIndex(cellAnchorPane);
int col = GridPane.getColumnIndex(cellAnchorPane);
```

*By the way I don't know what you are trying to achieve but I Don't think the button need to be Inside an AnchorPane. And create a chessBoard in fxml instead of code will be really repetitive*

Look at this sample app. You can create an handler and pass those parameter

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridpane, 400, 400);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            Button b = new Button("cell " + i + " - " + j);
            final int col = i;
            final int row = j;
            b.setOnAction(a -> buttonClicked(col, row));
            gridpane.add(new AnchorPane(b), i, j);
        }

    }

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();



}

    private void buttonClicked(int col, int row) {
        System.out.println("button : " + col + " -" + row + " pressed");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Answer updated : By code a simple for loop is enough and you can pass all the parameter you want.

Comment: why would you add the button into an anchorPane instead of just insert it into the gridPane directly?

Comment: Yeah that was the point I mention in my answer too, i try to reproduce what there was in the fxml